# Missing launcher 14.04

Tags: unity

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 for some time without problems. However my launcher has just disappeared and I cannot access any applications. My wallpaper and documents on the desktop appear and when I go to a guest session the launcher appears and ubuntu works perfectly. I get an error message upon opening which reads:

could not apply stored configuration for monitors.
Error on line 1 char 1 document empty or white noise.

I have thought about simply reloading my saved files into a new user but do not want to waste so much disk space.

I assume I have a corrupted configuration file and wondered about simply copying this from one of the working users into my setup. However, I don't know which file this is likely to be this should be easy to identify as it will be empty! Can anyone help?

Many thanks